# What does "at the business end of a bullhorn" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Only 12% of campaigns run for less than a week. That allows plenty of time for on-the-go learning to emerge. Letting learning from the previous mailing to inform the next one turns a series of messages into a managed conversation over time.
>   And an engaging conversation's a lot more fun than being at the business end of a **bullhorn**.

What does bullhorn mean here?
And what dose this sentence mean ? "And an engaging conversation's a lot more fun than being at the business end of a bullhorn."

Comment: According to [Free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bullhorn): " A portable device consisting of a microphone attached to a loudspeaker, used especially to amplify the voice."

Comment: @Farooq I know this meaning, but I think here it has different meaning.

Comment: @Farooq: user123 has a point.  This word is being used metaphorically here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bullhorn:

[image: Bullhorn]

The 'business end' of something is the end at which its operation becomes effective, so the 'business end of a bullhorn' is the end where the sound comes out. To be at the business end of a bullhorn is to endure somebody yelling at you.

Comment: One should add that bullhorn is AmE for megaphone.

Comment: Nice picture!  LOL  Gets the point across perfectly.